# addEventListener for an array to change multiple button colors?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom

It keeps telling me buttonArray.addEventListener is not a function, and I'm unsure why.  Still new to JS any help is appreciated.

Tried doing a forEach didn't help.

```
let button = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');
console.log(button);

let buttonArray = Array.from(button);

buttonArray.addEventListener('mouseover', event => {
    event.target.style.color = 'red';
});
```

Comment: Any reason you're not using a simple CSS rule `.btn:hover { color: red; }` ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach the event listener to the buttons themselves and not the array of buttons. Try this

```
 let button = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');
 console.log(button);

 let buttonArray = Array.from(button);

 buttonArray.forEach(btn => {
   btn.addEventListener('mouseover', event => {
     event.target.style.color = 'red';
   });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this,You are returning an array and you have to add the event to every element

```js
let button = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');
console.log(button);

let buttonArray = Array.from(button);//this is an array here
console.log(buttonArray)
//using foreach to add eventlistener to every element in array
buttonArray.forEach(a=>a.addEventListener('mouseover', event => {
    event.target.style.color = 'red';
}))
```

```html
<button class="btn">hello</button>
<button class="btn">hello</button>
<button class="btn">hello</button>
<button class="btn">hello</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through whole array using `for of` and `addEventListener` to them in `loop`

```
let button = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');
console.log(button);

let buttonArray = Array.from(button);
for(let button of buttonArray){
    button.addEventListener('mouseover', event => {
        event.target.style.color = 'red';
    });
}
```